# Calculate matrix rows with a vector using apply variation with multiple arguments

Tags: r, vector, matrix, apply

I am using R language to find *square of* [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) from each of the  matrix row values to a specified vector with each row and the vector are points for comparing two points I create this function

```
euclDist <- function(p1, p2){
   sum((p1 - p2)^2)
}
```

Now I want to create a function that finds row in the matrix that have minimum Euclidean distance to a specified point

```
  minDist<- function(points, p){
    dist = c()
    for(i in seq(1:length(points[,1])))
      dist[i] = euclDist2(points[i,], p)
    which.min(dist)
 }
```

For example

```
points = matrix(c(1:24), ncol=4)
p = c(1,2,1,2)
print(minDist(points, p))
```

The result is **1** as first row has minimum distance to the point p

This works fine but I want to get rid of the for loop by using one of the [apply](http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/a-brief-introduction-to-apply-in-r/) variations but I can not find one that works with matrix row by row and have multiple arguments support.

Edit: this question is revised as first code had some problem with brackets and parentheses :-(

Comment: Your loop doesn't work: `length(points, 1)`

Comment: Also, you have variables `dist` and `dis`

Comment: And there's a missing closing `)` in `for(i in...` also note that `points` and `p` have different dimensions, `points` has 6 obs per col and `p` is a vector with only 4 elements.

Comment: Sorry I extracted this code from more complex code then change it on the fly now I fix all problem and its working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
minDist <- function(points, p) which.min(apply(points, 1, euclDist, p2 = p))
```

but in general, `apply` is not a lot faster than a plain `for` loop. I can see two ways to write much more efficient code:

The first one uses R vectorization and recycling:

```
minDist <- function(points, p) which.min(colSums((t(points) - p)^2))
```

The second one uses the `rdist` function from the `fields` package, which can compute the euclidean distances between two sets of points:

```
minDist <- function(points, p) {
    require(fields)
    which.min(rdist(points, t(matrix(p))))
}
```

Either solution should be a lot faster than using `apply`.

Comment: Thank you very much the first one is brilliant and I took it

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is how to use apply instead of your for loop, the following will do it.

**To get back a vector:**

```
   dist <- sapply(points, euclDist, p)   # no need for the dist <- c()
```

**To get back a list:**

```
   dist <- lapply(points, euclDist, p)   # no need for the dist <- c()
```

However, please note that there are a few other issues with your code. Most notably, I'm not sure you are calculating the Euclidean Distance

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I am very sorry that my code does not work but now I fixed it can you please answer me according to the fixed one because sapply does not give me what I expect from it

Comment: If you can show what output you expect and that your `for` loop is giving you that output, I would be happy to show you how it relates to the `lapply` / `sapply` implementation here